# Date with time zone in simple camel for Auckland

Tags: java, timezone, apache-camel

I am looking for the time zone command specific to NewZealand Auckland instead of CET. I already tried with NZST `${date-with-timezone:now:NZST:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}`, which did not work.

Answer (score 0):

For New Zealand, the correct timezone IDs are `NZ` and `NST` so in your case the simple expression could be `date-with-timezone:now:NZ:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm` or `date-with-timezone:now:NST:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm`.

Comment: I used NZ and is working now. Thanks!